# How to mass remove different text value within paragraph

Tags: html, mysql, wordpress

I am totally new to this, and was wondering if there is any way how I can bulk remove certain part from WordPress posts.
I have posts that contains:

```html
<!-- wp:paragraph --><br>
<p><!--<br><strong><span style="color: #5ea5d0;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;">SOME RANDOM TEXT</span></span></strong> --></p><br>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

So as you can see, this text is commented < !-- > 
But I have some posts that needs to display that text, and that text is always different on different posts (That's why some posts do not have it)

Is there a way to do a sql query where I can lets say do this:

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace (post_content, '<!-- wp:paragraph -->
    <p><!-- <br><strong><span style="color: #5ea5d0;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"> SOME RANDOM TEXT</span></span></strong> --></p>
    <!-- /wp:paragraph -- >', '');
```

but in that matter to remove all of the commented/unnecessary  parts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mysql 8.x, it has a `REGEXP_REPLACE` function. You can see [official documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace)

For lower versions, you can use user defined functions like [this one](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp)

Also - it is not clear whether you want to match based on `SOME RANDOM TEXT` OR the html tags surrounding them, or a combination of both.

Comment: Hi, 
I want to remove the html tags, including the text inside. That text is not the same on all of the posts, so if I just remove the html tags, the text remains visible, and is not matching the content.

Comment: in REG-REPLACE you use (*) instead of the text, with mysql 5.x it gets complicated